# How do I access the DLC BGM?

Tags: persona-5

I bought the Persona 3 and 4 Costume and BGM DLC packs, but I can't seem to find a way to change the BGM. The costumes were in a cardboard box in my room, but there wasn't any mention of how to enable the music. I've looked in the settings menu, as well, but no dice.

How do I turn the DLC music on/off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike the costumes, where the usage guidance is told explicitly to you, the BGM is toggled by changing the Protagonist's costume to the corresponding DLC costume.

Thus, if you want to hear the Persona 3 DLC BGM, you need to have your Protagonist equip the Gekkoukan High uniform DLC costume.

For reference, this is explained [here](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/835628-persona-5/75227890):

> how do i change the music in persona 5 to the dlc music
>
> Put the dlc costume on the MC